# Bathroom break during maariv

Tags: halacha, tefilla, bathroom, maariv

If a person begins Maariv and has just answered Barchu, and then realizes that they are going to have to go to the bathroom before they can say Shemoneh Esrei, when is the best time to go?  Should they go immediately and not say Shema with the congregation, go after they finish Shema and not be there for Hashem Elokeichem Emes, or speed ahead and go after finishing everything up until Shemoneh Esrei and miss answering Amen to the berachos leading up to Shemoneh Esrei, and possibly Kaddish?

I am assuming that the person will make it back to start Shemoneh Esrei with the tzibbur no matter which of the above options he chooses.  Thus I am not including the option of leaving after Kaddish or immediately before Kaddish, when I assume it is unreasonable to get back to start with the tzibbur.

Comment: Can he hold it in for 72 minutes or not ?

Comment: @eramm That is a halacha in being yotzei b'dieved. If you check yourself and realize you have to go at all, even if you can wait 72 minutes, you l'chatchillah have to go before you daven.  I am asking what you should do, not what worked after the fact. Shulchan Aruch O.C. 92:1

Comment: It sounds like you are saying in all cases he will say all the parts of "Shema and its blessings" before starting Shmoneh Esrei. Is this accurate? Your only question is which communal aspects of the initial sections he should skip?

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes - the question is which part to miss having participated in with the tzibbur. He won't skip saying anything, just some part won't be with the tzibbur.

Comment: Also in all cases does he say all the parts of "Shema and its blessings" without interruption, or in some does he break in between Bracha X and Bracha Y?

Comment: @DoubleAA I think in the options that I gave, the only interruption I offered was between the end of Shema and what follows.  The other cases were either at the beginning or the end.

Comment: You're not allowed to daven if you need the bathroom. If i find the source, I'll add it as an answer

Comment: No time for a full answer but I think if you learn the relevant chapters in Rav Ovadiah's kitzur then the answer should be clear. http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01355_part_1.html#HtmpReportNum0003_L2 AND http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01355_part_6.html#HtmpReportNum0008_L2